# PHP undefined Constant Error while using ont defined value, Any other alternative

Tags: php, undefined, constants

PHP undefined Constant Error while using not `!defined` value, Any other alternative.

My Code :-

```
<a href="http://'.<?php !defined(DOMAIN) ? print('localhost') : print(MY_DOMAIN); ?>.'" target='_blank'>My Website</a>
```

but this is giving me Error :

```
<a href="http://<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Use of undefined constant DOMAIN - assumed 'DOMAIN' in <b>C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\url.php</b> on line <b>3</b><br />localhost" target='_blank'>My Website</a>
```

**Should not it just have to print localhost if I don't use** :-

```
define('DOMAIN', 'example.com');
```

Is there other way arround to specify !defined value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got to encase the name of constants in quotes.

```
<a href="http://'.<?php !defined("DOMAIN") ? print('localhost') : print(DOMAIN); ?>.'" target='_blank'>My Website</a>
```

---

Otherwise it would work like this: (because you are going to pass the value of const)

```
define("DOMAIN", 'example.com');
```

`defined(DOMAIN)` will equal `defined('example.com')`

Comment: e.g. `defined(DOMAIN)` is trying to pass an undefined constant to the `defined()` function. while `defined('DOMAIN')` is passing a STRING that the defined function will then used to check if a constant of that name actually exists.